# Can i run javascript in global execution context without eval

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I am writing php framework that extracts Javascript blocks to merge, minify and execute them asynchronously.

So i like to delay Javascript code execution, to do that i wrap the javascript in

```
MyLib.then(function(){
//orignial code from the templates....
}
```

this works fine unless the wrapped code needs to create global variables
(i am not the author of the wrapped code, so i do not want to fix that code)
instead i like to run that code in a global execution context.

for example:

```
//excample code not within my controle  
var global="Hello World";
```

would become:

```
MyLib.then(function(){
   //excample code not within my controle  
   var global="Hello World";
}
```

the solution right now is to put the javascript into an string and then

```
MyLib.then(function(){
     $.globalEval("var global=\"Hello World\"";");
}
```

or with the globalEval call within my library

```
MyLib.then("var global=\"Hello World\"";")
```

but i would like to stick to the better readable version, which is also easier to debug for users of the framework.

```
MyLib.then(function(){
   var global="Hello World";
}
```

and change the execution context within my lib by using
callback.call(window) or something like that, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yea. You can add it to the window / document objects.

For example: `window.var  = "Hello"`

When using the window object it can be accessed from anywhere. You could also create your own global object.

Comment: @Keywan Ghadami What do you mean?

Comment: the code var global="Hello World" stands as example for javascript that is written by other developers and should continue to run. Even if its wrapped within my code. I can not change that code, only the way how it's wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare your variable in global context and then initialize it in a scope:

```
var globalVariable;
MyLib.then(function(){
    globalVariable = "a value";
});
```

If your code already runs inside a scope you can go ahead with this:

```
(function(global){
    // my logic
    global.myVar = "a value";
})(this);
```